# Spring modular mvc web application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, architecture

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I'll try it. I'm original a php developer and now want to try out to create a modular java web application in spring. This seemed to be much more complicated than I used to be or than i expected it.. I google a lot for many hours but i didn't found a suitable solution (or i didn't noticed that...) so i really tried to find out a solution by myself...

I want to have a project structured like this:

> main project (parent-project: with common classes and all the login-stuff)
>
> - modul A: for example a "wheels-admin"
> - modul B: for example a "car-admin" which has a dependeny to modul A
> - modul C: for example a "shop-system" which has a dependency to modul A and C

Modules A and B are only available when the user is successfully locked in. The main-project is the parent of all modules and all classes of the main-project are reachable in the modules.

Ok and now my "additional" requirement. Each of the projects and modules has to be a web application, because they also have the static resource stuff (like css, js, jps/html...) and not only services/classes. So I don't want to share only services, that's why I understand that I couldn't create the modules as a jar. I want to divide parts of the application into separate modules (war). In my understanding it isn't possible to create wars as a dependency in a mvc web application because it's also a war.

**EDIT: Major question**:
How can i split a spring mvc web application into several modules? But not only the services, also the statis/resource stuff. In other words, how can i create a web application with multiple war-files?

**detailed questions**:

1. Is the answer of my question to create only on mvc web application and create the "modules" only with a sub folder structur? So they aren't realy modules and more parts of only one application. (I wouldn't like that!)
2. Is the solution a "gemini blueprint" application? If so, could you provide me a link to tutorial or something like this, where a modular web application is described?
3. Is the answer of my question to create multiple stand alone mvc web applications? If so, how do i create an application context? For example, how does the module know that a user was logged in, in the parent project? Do i have to configure everything in each module (for example database connection
4. Is there an other way to "share" services and resource-files and so on as dependeny?
5. I know it's possible an EAR-project which include some war-files and something like this... or maven-parent-project that is able to "import" other web applications (the modules)...But how can run this on the webserver to start the complete web application?

At the end, I only want a modular web application where separate parts of the application is "outsourced" into a module. If you have another solution, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the subject area, but this seems like it's really broad. You should see if you can focus your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at Jhipster (Spring MVC + AngularJs + Boot + ...). They've created a [micro-services architecture](http://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/)

It is very easy to do a 'main' application with all the usermanagement, and securing the communication to the other services.

All the modules are different jar's with embedded tomcat's, running each on a different port. So initially, you can run them all on the same machine.